# How Viola-Jones face detector work for multiple size of faces?

Tags: haar-wavelet, viola-jones

I am implementing Viola-Jones face detector to detect faces in still images and it work preety for images having same size as of my training size. However I am not getting how the face detector work for multiple size faces?

If the training size of my images is 24*24 and if I want to detect faces in detector window of 30*30 how I need to rescale the haar-feature so that it will work for 30*30 size detector window working with the same threshold.

One more thing, do the position of Haar-feature also changes with different size detector window and if yes how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you're representing a rectangle found inside a Haar wavelet with `x`, `y`, `w` and `h` variables where `x` and `y` represent to top left corner of the rectangle **relative to the detector's top left boundaries**, `w` its width and `h` its height. You can rescale the whole detector by a factor `s` each Haar wavelet rectangle with the following pseudo-code:

```
for all rectangle i in the Haar wavelet do
    tempRectangle = rectangle[i];
    tempRectangle.x = tempRectangle.x * s
    tempRectangle.y = tempRectangle.y * s
    tempRectangle.h = tempRectangle.h * s
    tempRectangle.w = tempRectangle.w * s

    //Read the pixels contained in tempRectangle region and
    //calculate this rectangle's contribution to the feature value
    //considering the respective weight of rectangle[i].
end for
```

So, let's assume that a single Haar-lke feature has the base size of 24x24 pixels. Such feature is composed of 2 rectangles `r1=(10,15,8,4)` and `r2=(4, 8, 8, 4)`, where `r=(x,y,w,h)`. When you rescale your detector by a factor `s=1.25`, this feature rectangles should become `r1=(12.5, 18.75, 10, 5)` and `r2=(5, 10, 10, 5)`.

Comment: Hi, you mean, if for 24*24 detector window my haar-feature of (x,y,w,h)=(10,15,8,4) then if I increment detector window by 1.25 then  haar feature value becomes (x,y,w,h)=(12.5,18.75,10,5). Is that so?

Comment: Can you please elaborate it by example. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please elaborate it by example. What does this mean 'calculate this rectangle's contribution to the feature value'?

Comment: I edited the answer to give a more detailed example. The comment about "calculate this rectangle's contribution..." is just a statement that normal Haar-like feature value calculation could happen where the comments were put if you are rescaling the detector at the same time as calculating the Haar-like feature value. If all you want is to rescale the detector window and its features, you may simply ignore those comments.